# Real-time Hand Recognition fail on 99% Accuracy CNN model

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I have trained a simple CNN model on a [hand gesture recognition dataset from kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/gti-upm/leapgestrecog/code?datasetId=39466&sortBy=voteCount). The testing accuracy of my CNN model was great even after 3 epochs (99%). Then, I have tried to build a real-time model that integrates my CNN model and recognizes gestures in real time. However, even when processing the real-time frame in the same manner as the ones used to train the model, the real-time model doesn't seem to be accurately predicting the gestures I'm showing through my camera. I have tried training the model using different parameters multiple times, I've also tried increasing the number of epochs but it doesn't seem to be working. For reference, the images in the dataset are black and white. Below is my CNN model and the real-time recognition model.

1- Reading the data:

```py
import os
import cv2
import numpy as np
from random import shuffle  
from zipfile import ZipFile
from PIL import Image
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random
from keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
from keras.optimizers import RMSprop,Adam
from tensorflow.keras import layers, models
from keras.models import save_model
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Flatten, Conv2D, MaxPool2D
from tensorflow.keras.utils import to_categorical             

# Reading the data (gestures images)
path = "C:/Users/User/Desktop/projects/Courses/Prodigy InfoTech/Task 4 (Hand Gesture Recognition)/leapGestRecog" # Gestures Path
hand_gestures = ["01_palm", "02_l", "03_fist", "04_fist_moved", "05_thumb", "06_index", "07_ok", "08_palm_moved", "09_c", "10_down"]
final_data = [] # An empty list to hold the dictionaries for each gesture.
image_size = (150, 150)

for file in range(10): # Looping through the 10 files containing the gestures.
    file_data = os.path.join(path, f"{file:02d}")
    for gesture in hand_gestures: # Looping through the gestures files.
        gestures_img = os.path.join(file_data, gesture)
        if os.path.exists(gestures_img):
            for filename in os.listdir(gestures_img): # Looping through the images in each gestures file.
                if filename.endswith((".png", ".jpg")):
                    image_path = os.path.join(gestures_img, filename)
                    image = cv2.imread(image_path, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
                    if image is not None: # Checking if it's a valid image
                        resized_image = cv2.resize(image, image_size)
                        final_data.append({"gesture": gesture, "image": resized_image})

total_count = len(final_data)
print(f"total data count: {total_count}")
```

2- preprocessing & CNN

```py
images = np.array([item['image'] for item in final_data])
labels = np.array([item['gesture'] for item in final_data])

images = np.array(images, dtype = 'float32')
labels = np.array(labels)
labels = labels.reshape(total_count, 1)
# Converting the labels to numerical representation
label_encoder = LabelEncoder()
labels = label_encoder.fit_transform(labels)
labels = to_categorical(labels)

# Splitting the data into training and testing sets
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(images, labels, test_size = 0.2, random_state = 42)
# CNN model
model = models.Sequential()
# 1st Layer
model.add(Conv2D(filters = 15, kernel_size = (5,5),padding = 'Same', 
                 activation ='relu', input_shape = (150, 150, 1)))
model.add(MaxPool2D(pool_size = (2,2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))

# 2nd layer
model.add(Conv2D(filters = 32, kernel_size = (3,3),padding = 'Same', 
                 activation ='relu'))
model.add(MaxPool2D(pool_size = (2,2), strides = (2,2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))

# Flatten
model.add(Flatten())

model.add(Dense(512, activation = "relu"))
model.add(Dense(len(hand_gestures), activation = 'softmax'))

# Inialize the optimizer
optimizer = Adam(learning_rate = 0.001, beta_1 = 0.9, beta_2 = 0.999)
# Compile the model
model.compile(optimizer = optimizer, loss = 'categorical_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'])

# Early stopping to avoid overfitting
early_stopping = EarlyStopping(monitor = 'val_loss', patience = 1, restore_best_weights = True)
# Train the model (training history)
history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs = 3, batch_size = 250, validation_data = (X_test, y_test), callbacks = [early_stopping])

# Evaluate the model
test_loss, test_acc = model.evaluate(X_test, y_test)
print(f"Test Accuracy: {test_acc}")
```

3- Real-time model:

```py
import cv2
import os
import numpy as np
from keras.models import load_model
# Load the pre-trained CNN model
model = load_model('C:/Users/User/Desktop/projects/Courses/Prodigy InfoTech/Task 4 (Hand Gesture Recognition)/CNN model_final.h5')
print(model.summary())
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Map labels back to gestures
gesture_mapping = {0: "01_palm", 1: "02_l", 2: "03_fist", 3: "04_fist_moved", 4: "05_thumb", 5: "06_index", 6: "07_ok", 7: "08_palm_moved", 8: "09_c", 9: "10_down"}

# Initialize the camera
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)  # Use 0 for default camera, you can change it if you have multiple cameras

while True:
    # Capture frame by frame
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    # Convert to Grayscale
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    # Resize the frame to match the model's input size
    resized_frame = cv2.resize(gray, (150, 150))

    # Reshape to match the shape of the input 
    input_data_arr = np.array(resized_frame)
    input_data = input_data_arr.reshape((1, 150, 150, 1))  # Ensure single channel

    # Model Prediction
    prediction = model.predict(input_data)
    predicted_label = np.argmax(prediction)

    print("Raw Prediction:", prediction)

    # Corresponding gesture label
    predicted_gesture = gesture_mapping[predicted_label]

    # Display the frame with the predicted gesture
    cv2.putText(frame, f"Predicted Gesture: {predicted_gesture}", (10, 30), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1, (0, 255, 0), 2)
    cv2.imshow('Hand Gesture Recognition', frame)
    print("Predicted Probabilities:", prediction)

    # Break loop when q is pressed
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

# Release the camera and close all windows
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I've tried changing the parameters, the number of epochs and the learning rate. I've also tried to change the pre-processing method of the images of the dataset. I've also tried changing the pre-processing of the real-time frames. I am expecting for the real-time model to successfully display the gestures shown through my camera as the CNN model's accuracy is super high 99%. I also know that it didn't overfit, see epochs report:

```
    Epoch 1/3
    64/64 [==============================] - 3848s 60s/step - loss: 49.2367 - accuracy: 0.5278 - val_loss: 0.4549 - val_accuracy: 0.9195
    Epoch 2/3
    64/64 [==============================] - 2130s 33s/step - loss: 0.0761 - accuracy: 0.9803 - val_loss: 0.1067 - val_accuracy: 0.9805
    Epoch 3/3
    64/64 [==============================] - 2547s 39s/step - loss: 0.0143 - accuracy: 0.9965 - val_loss: 0.0483 - val_accuracy: 0.9930
    125/125 [==============================] - 175s 1s/step - loss: 0.0483 - accuracy: 0.9930
    Test Accuracy: 0.9929999709129333
```

Comment: The kaggle dataset is "golden". What i mean by that is: the dataset contains only hand images and hand gestures. Does your real time image also contain only the hand? Maybe the problem is that you have the background in the real time image. 

If that is the case, you should consider a segmentation CNN to extract the hand from the image.

Comment: @VitorPereiraMatias I suppose you're right, the images in the dataset don't seem to be showing much of the background and one would only notice what's in the background if they look close enough. I think this might be the problem in the real-time part, the images I show with my camera do have a background and I'm directly converting the image to grayscale before processing the hand gesture. I'll try segmenting and update you on the performance.